# Why is there no documentation for Next-Auth get authorization url error?

Tags: next-auth

I get this error when trying to signin using next-auth:

```
[next-auth][error][get_authorization_url_error] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#get_authorization_url_error {
  statusCode: 503...
```

There documentation says very little about the error https://next-auth.js.org/errors#get_authorization_url_error. Has anyone gotten this error before, or if not, can you direct me to a link that has more information?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be getting a 503 when requesting the authorization URL from your oauth provider. This generally means some provider settings (either from you or from next-auth) are incorrect. A 503 almost makes me think the URL you're trying to hit to generate the authenticationUrl might have a typo or something.

Can you provide some more details about your setup? `[...nextauth].js` file, versions of next-auth and next.js, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Turns out i hadn't added my `clientId` and `clientSecret` in `[...nextauth].js` like so.

```
  GoogleProvider({
    clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    httpOptions: {
      timeout: 40000,
    },
    authorization: {
      params: {
        prompt: "consent",
        access_type: "offline",
        response_type: "code",
      },
    },
  }),
```

You can get these from [here](https://console.developers.google.com/)